# pandasデータへ変換する方法を教えて下さい。

Tags: python, pandas, グラフ理論

pythonのループの仕方を教えて下さい。
よろしくお願いします。

(参考)無向グラフと有向グラフ＞無向グラフの隣接行列(adjacency matrix)
http://www.dais.is.tohoku.ac.jp/~shioura/teaching/ad11/ad11-09.pdf#page=5

```
import pandas as pd
# input  : 線分a [0,1]
#          線分b [0,2]
#          線分c [0,3]
#          線分d [1,2]
#          線分e [2,3]
#          線分f [3,4]

# スクリプト???

# output
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [[0,1,1,1,0],
     [1,0,1,0,0],
     [1,1,0,1,0],
     [1,0,1,0,1],
     [0,0,0,1,0]],
     index  =["0","1","2","3","4"],
     columns=["0","1","2","3","4"])
print(df)
#    0  1  2  3  4
# 0  0  1  1  1  0
# 1  1  0  1  0  0
# 2  1  1  0  1  0
# 3  1  0  1  0  1
# 4  0  0  0  1  0
```

(参考)[線分群から、閉図形の数を数える方法を教えて下さい。](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/49392/%e7%b7%9a%e5%88%86%e7%be%a4%e3%81%8b%e3%82%89-%e9%96%89%e5%9b%b3%e5%bd%a2%e3%81%ae%e6%95%b0%e3%82%92%e6%95%b0%e3%81%88%e3%82%8b%e6%96%b9%e6%b3%95%e3%82%92%e6%95%99%e3%81%88%e3%81%a6%e4%b8%8b%e3%81%95%e3%81%84)

2018-10-24--------------------------------------------------------------------------
magichan様 ありがとうございます。ループについて、少しわかりました。
この配列lstに,「1」を入力する方法を教えて下さい。(例.線分aより,1行2列目,2行1列目=1)
よろしくお願いします。

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
array2 = np.array([[0,1],[0,2],[0,3],[1,2],[2,3],[3,4]])
array1 = set(np.sort(array2.ravel()))
lst = np.zeros((len(array1),len(array1)),dtype =int)
df = pd.DataFrame(lst,index  =array1,columns=array1)
print(df)
#    0  1  2  3  4
# 0  0  0  0  0  0
# 1  0  0  0  0  0
# 2  0  0  0  0  0
# 3  0  0  0  0  0
# 4  0  0  0  0  0
```

2018-10-25--------------------------------------------------------------------------
できました。ループを短くする方法があれば、教えて下さい。よろしくお願いします。

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
def getNearestValue(list, num):
    """
    Pythonのリスト要素からある値と最も近い値を取り出す
    https://qiita.com/icchi_h/items/fc0df3abb02b51f81657
    """
    idx = np.abs(np.asarray(list) - num).argmin()
    return list[idx]
array2 = np.array([[0,1],[0,2],[0,3],[1,2],[2,3],[3,4]])
array1 = list(set(np.sort(array2.ravel())))
lst = np.zeros((len(array1),len(array1)),dtype =int)
i=0
for x in range(len(array2)):
    ir=getNearestValue(array1,array2[i,0])
    ic=getNearestValue(array1,array2[i,1])
    lst[ir,ic]=1
    lst[ic,ir]=1
    i += 1
df = pd.DataFrame(lst,index  =array1,columns=array1)
print(df)
#    0  1  2  3  4
# 0  0  1  1  1  0
# 1  1  0  1  0  0
# 2  1  1  0  1  0
# 3  1  0  1  0  1
# 4  0  0  0  1  0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

とりあえず書いてみました。

やりたいことはこういうことでしょうかね？

```
import pandas as pd

lst = []
for name in list('abcdef'):
    lst.append(list(map(int, input("線分{} :".format(name)).split(","))))
df = pd.DataFrame(lst)
tbl = pd.concat([df,df.rename(columns={0:1,1:0})])
result = tbl.pivot(index=0,columns=1,values=True).notna().astype(int)
print(result)

# (実行結果)
#線分a :0,1
#線分b :0,2
#線分c :0,3
#線分d :1,2
#線分e :2,3
#線分f :3,4
#1  0  1  2  3  4
#0
#0  0  1  1  1  0
#1  1  0  1  0  0
#2  1  1  0  1  0
#3  1  0  1  0  1
#4  0  0  0  1  0
```